# Popen read data before CTRL+C command is issued

Tags: python, c

I have a command line tool written in C for windows that scans for bluetooth devices via a serial USB Dongle.

It will loop through all devices in range repeating until it receives a CTRL+C command.

```
device1 name firmware
device2 name firmware
device3 name firmware
device1 name firmware
device2 name firmware
device3 name firmware
...
```

I want to stop the scan when it reaches a certain device so I can issue an update firmware command.

At the moment I can only capture the output after the CTRL+C command is issued using the following function that starts the scan, sleeps, then issues the CTRL+C command, I then catch the error and process the output in the `except` block:

```
        command = [self.cli_tool, '-s']

        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

        stream = []

        if self.check_dongle_firmware() is not False:
            try:                    
                self.proc = subprocess.Popen(
                            command, 
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, 
                            startupinfo=startupinfo)

                time.sleep(SCAN_TIMEOUT)
                os.kill(self.proc.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
                self.proc.wait()

            except KeyboardInterrupt:                
                for line in self.proc.stdout:
                    stream.append(line)                         

                for x in stream[7:]:
                    x = x.decode()
                    print(x.strip())
```

I want something like this:

```
stream = []

 self.proc = subprocess.Popen(
                            command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, 
                            startupinfo=startupinfo)

for line in self.proc.stdout:
    stream.append(line) 
    if 'device2' in line.decode().split():
        os.kill(self.proc.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
        self.proc.wait()
```

This does not work though.  It will not read 1 line at a time and the CTRL+C event is never reached.

I need to read and process 1 line at a time so that i can stop the process at a certain device.

Currently it only reads an empty byte or string depending on the pipe attributes.

printing to the screen (With the startup info off) or saving to a file without issuing a CTRL+C will render empty.
I tried various combinations using :

`universal_newlines=True`

`bufsize=1`

`self.proc.communicate()[0]`

When I try the code using a command like `ping` I have no problem and full control of the output.

I have searched SO for tried anything that looks similar but nothing works for what I need.

I think I am missing something obvious or it is not possible due to the tool  not applying a flush command in the C code?

Any direction or advice is appreciated!

In the C code I have fflush only in the following locations which i presume to be for error handling.

`project.h` in both `bootloader\src\common\` and `receiver\src\common\`

```
//*************************************************************************
//------------------------- assertion of errors  --------------------------
//*************************************************************************
/*
 *   The format is assert(eval, error);
 *
 *   If 'eval' equals 0 then there is an error printed with number 'error'.
 *
 */

#define ERR_STACKOVERFLOW 0   // Out of stack space
#define ERR_SCH_OVERFLOW  1   // Scheduler overflow
#define ERR_SCH_OUTRANGE  2   // Scheduler out of range
#define ERR_WSHRS_OUTRANGE  3   // Scheduler out of range

#ifdef __nDEBUG__

#include "./error/error.h"
....
#include <stdio.h>
#define DBG_PRINT(a, args...) { printf(a, ##args);fflush(stdout); }
```

Comment: *This does not work* just means nothing. Please say what you would expect, and what actually happens.

Comment: Read the whole thing. I clearly stated what I expected at the top.  Regardless I will state more explicitly for you\

Comment: Yeah, but actually happens? BTW, **you** have a problem, **I** don't. If you don't want to answer my questions, it is no problem but I won't be able to help you...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Apologies, I hope things are clearer now and I will appreciate any input :) Please advise if I need to add any more info!

Comment: While not too familiar with Windows console, this might have something to do with how your external program writes to console. AIUI, Windows console is quite a different beast from Unixy stdin/stdout/stderr terminal, even in C standard library tries its best to make it look like one. As an experiment, can use it as part of pipe on command line (like just `| more` as simplest test).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is probably, that the output of your CLI program is block buffered, since the output file descriptor is not associated with a terminal. You claim, that it works with "ping" instead of your cli program, so it definitively has to be an issue with the subprocess itself.

Since you programmed the cli program yourself, make sure that it does not buffer the output (i.e. put an `fflush()` after each line which is printed.

Specifically, adjust the code looks like this:

```
while (somecondition) {
    ...
    printf("%s %s %s\n", device, name, firmware);
    fflush(stdout); // <- Add this line after the printf
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, as melpomene suggested, you can also switch stdout to be line buffered early in the program with:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

[Online C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 7.21.3/3:

> When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment. Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may be affected via the `setbuf` and `setvbuf` functions.

7.21.3/7:

> At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly — *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output). As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

Comment: I did not program the C program myself.  The output is described as a 'Buffered Output" .  I suspected that a lack of fflush() was the problem (with my limited knowledge of C).

I have access to the source code which is many files in many folders. Can you provide an example in C of how one would a. send out data line by line to STDOUT and one that would use block buffering.  This way I may be able to identify the problem code and express these concerns to the original C developer

Comment: one other thing.  Is it a limitation of the program that it HAS to be buffered or is it possible to do the fflush().

Comment: No, a program never _has_ to buffer its io, it is just a bit more efficient sometimes. But this is not an issue here with such terse output.

Comment: The only fflush i can find is in the `bootloader` and `receiver` files.... both are identical and I assume limited to Errors.. I have included the code in my question

Comment: @jonashu You need to look where the output you want to parse happens. The fflush there is _missing_ you have to _add_ it there.

Comment: Alternatively, put `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);` at the beginning of `main()`.

Comment: Just to be clear the `data` is coming directly from a temperature sensor using `bluetooth`.  If I use `setvbuf` , will this be a problem for the data transfer when used in another part of the code?  maybe for the `scan` block buffering is not needed but for the data tranfser, it may be necessary. it is a very low powered device which is why it was implemented.

Comment: data transfer being the temperature readings, up to 2 years worth which can take some time

Comment: This change _only_ affects the interaction between the cli program and the terminal (or whatever your stdout is). It has nothing to do with the device communication.

Comment: It saves the data to a csv file from the commandline.. This will not use STDOUT but a separate process??.. Naturally I do not want to break anything!

Comment: I can assure you that the proposed modifications cannot break anything, but of course you will test it cautiosly, won't you?